# How to get Product Category name and Category ID on checkout success page?

Tags: magento-1.8, checkout, category

I am looking for a way to get Category name and Category ID one the checkout success page. So far I have added the product name, sku etc but I am unable to get the category name and id

Here's my code to product attributes and category names:

```
<?php //
    $products = array();
    $lastOrderId = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getLastOrderId();
    $_order = Mage::getSingleton('sales/order')->load($lastOrderId);

/* @var $item Mage_Sales_Model_Order */
foreach ($_order->getAllVisibleItems()  as $item) {
    $info['sku'] = trim($item->getSku());
    $info['qty'] = $item->getQtyOrdered();
    $info['price'] = $item->getPrice();
    $info['name'] = $item->getName();

    $products[] = $info;
}

    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);
    $categoryIds = $product->getCategoryIds();
    $categoryName = '';
if (isset($categoryIds[0])){
    $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())->load($categoryIds[0]);
    $categoryName['category'] = $category->getName();
}

$config['productInfos'] = $products;
$config['cartTotal'] = $_order->getGrandTotal();
$config['currency'] = Mage::app()->getBaseCurrencyCode();
?>
```

Here we echo out the values:

```
_roi.push(['_addItem',
    '<?php echo $product['sku']; ?>', // Merchant SKU
    '<?php echo $product['name']; ?>', // Product Name
    '<?php echo $categoryIds['categoryId']; ?>', // Category ID
    '<?php echo $categoryName['category']; ?>', // Category Name
    '<?php echo $product['price']; ?>', // Unit Price
    '<?php echo $product['qty']; ?>' // Item Quantity
]);
```

The issue is the CategoryIds and CategoryName are not showing and I'm stuck!

Anyone able to help please do?

Comment: You haven't defined the $productId variable. It could be retrieved as $item->getData('product_id').

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`$_item['product_id']` is a product id . We will find out categoryid associate with product.

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_item['product_id']);
$cats = $product->getCategoryIds();
```

Now we have category ID(s). One product can associate with more then one categorys. This is Magento default nature.

```
 foreach ($cats as $category_id) {
    $_cat = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())->load($category_id);
        echo $_cat->getName();             
    }
```

`$_cat->getName();`   is your product category name. This is beneficial if product is associate with a single category. if product is associate with multiple category then we need category ID to get product category name.

i hope this will little helpful for you

Answer (score 2):

Use product ID :

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);
$categoryIds = $product->getCategoryIds();
$categoryName = '';
if (isset($categoryIds[0])){
$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())->load($categoryIds[0]);
$categoryName = $category->getName();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

When you loaded order, it contains ordered items, not products. 
To get products from items, you should get item_id for each product, and load products by that Id, and **only then** get categories data for this products.

When you do `$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId)`, it receives no product ID, as `$productId` is not defined. You can assign it to `$item->getData('product_id');`

Answer (score 1):

Things to note:

1. `$categoryIds =  $product->getCategoryIds();` will give categories ids
   in comma separated system (1,2,3,4) so you need to explode this into
   individual values and then load category (ONLY IF A PRODUCT CAN BE
   IN MULTIPLE CATEGORIES).
2. `$categoryName = '';` This should be `$categoryName = array();`

Answer (score 1):

Shopping.com doesn't say anything about possibility to put few categories for one item, so it means that somehow you need to choose one main category from array.

in my case i randomly choosing the second id from array if array is exist.
Hope it will help to somebody because I was looking solution for this for a while.

```
<?php
 $items = $order->getAllItems();
foreach ($items as $item){

$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($item['product_id']);
$cats = $product->getCategoryIds();

if (is_array($cats)){
    $_cat = $cats[2]; 
}
else $_cat = $cats;
$_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())->load($_cat);
?>


<script type="text/javascript">
_roi.push(['_addItem', 
'<?php echo $item->getSku();?>', // Merchant sku
'<?php echo $item->getName();?>', // Product name
'<?php echo $_cat;?>', // Category id
'<?php echo $_category->getName();?>', // Category name
'<?php echo $item->getPrice();?>', // Unit price
'<?php echo $item->getQtyToShip();?>' // Item quantity
]);

</script>
<?php

}

?>
```