# product category in detail

Tags: magento-1.9

how get product's category in

```
Product id :1 
Product Url :http://127.0.0.1/magento/emarsy-catalogfeed.php/t-shirt.html 
product Name:T-shirt 
product Image:http://127.0.0.1/magento/media/catalog/productno_selection
category :
Product Price :340.0000 
Product Description :T-shirt 
Msrp : 
Avaliable:1 
brand :
```

Comment: refer http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/56438/2443

Comment: @imtiaz there are too many already answer available on this website.

Answer (score 2):

Try this -

```
 $Category=Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($cat);
    $name=$Category->getName();
    $url=$Category->getUrl();
    $image=$Category->getImageUrl()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$categoryIds = $product->getCategoryIds();
foreach ($categoryIds as $categoryId) {
    $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())->load($categoryId);
    echo $category->getName();
}
```

Comment: Please add an explanation of your code

Answer (score 0):

there is two way in magento where you can goto product page

1) searching (quick,advanced)

2) category to product

if you visit product page from category then you can get category detail as below

```
<?php 
$_category_detail=Mage::registry('current_category');
echo  $_category_detail->getName(); //gives current  category name
echo $_category_detail->getId(); //gives current category id
?>
```

and if you visit product from searching then you can get all categories from below code

```
 $categoryIds = $product->getCategoryIds();
 foreach ($categoryIds as $categoryId) {
     $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($categoryId);
     echo $category->getName();
 }
```